# wxPython - text from file to string

Tags: string, text, wxpython

I was searching on the internet but without any conclusion. I don´t know how to open file, find word open and then go one line under line with open and print the line. Here is my code, but i think it´s totally wrong:

```
    def wstart(self, event):
    pnfl = codecs.open("Save/savegame.txt", "r")
    txtline = pnfl.readline()
    while txtline <> "open":
        txtline = pnfl.readline()
    txtline = pnfl.readline()
    print txtline
    pnfl.close()
```

Please help somebody i really don´t know how to fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to   open and read a file:

```
with open("your.txt",'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if "open" in line:
            print f.next() # print the line after the line with open in it
```

Comment: Thank you very much and I am sorry if somebody get confused of my really "gut" English :)

Comment: No problem, your English is much better than my Slovakian no doubt ;)